# How to use if statement in Marketing Cloud SQL activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

In the syncronized  data extensions Account__c i have the following fields:

- `KPIUltimoSoggiornoTipo__c` that is mapped with a list of products name (it is a text field)
- `KPIClusterFrequenza__c` indecates the frequency (first timer or repeater)

`IF KPIUltimoSoggiornoTipo__c = 'stagionali'` i want to associate both `KPIClusterFrequenza__c ='Repeater'` and `KPIClusterFrequenza__c = 'first_timer'`

`If  KPIUltimoSoggiornoTipo__c != 'stagionali'`
I want to associate only `KPIClusterFrequenza__c ='Repeater'`

I set up the following instructions, but they are not working:

```sql
IF (B.KPIUltimoSoggiornoTipo__c = 'STAGIONALI')
then B.KPIClusterFrequenza__c = 'REPEATER' OR B.KPIClusterFrequenza__c = 'FIRST_TIMER'
ELSE B.KPIClusterFrequenza__c = 'REPEATER'
```

What do I miss?
Thank you in advance, for your kind help

Comment: You need to use a CASE statement

Comment: @zuzannamj thank for your answer. What is the correct syntax for this Case statement. I've tried the following, but it says the syntax is not correct: 
CASE 
WHEN KPIUltimoSoggiornoTipo__c = 'STAGIONALI' THEN then KPIClusterFrequenza__c = 'REPEATER' OR KPIClusterFrequenza__c = 'FIRST_TIMER'
WHEN KPIUltimoSoggiornoTipo__c != 'STAGIONALI' THEN KPIClusterFrequenza__c = 'FIRST_TIMER

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use [CASE Expression](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp).

Syntax:

```
CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
    WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
    ELSE result
END;
```

Assuming you are querying from a child BU, then it would be something like:

```SQL
SELECT
KPIUltimoSoggiornoTipo__c,
CASE
    WHEN KPIUltimoSoggiornoTipo__c = 'STAGIONALI' THEN 'REPEATER'
    ELSE 'FIRST_TIMER'
END AS KPIClusterFrequenza__c 
FROM
ENT.[Your syncronized Account DE name]
```